# join 2 similar tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables:

```
table1
    id someval 
    -----------
    1      23  
    2      56  
    3      76  
    4     456  
    5      53  
    6      67  
    7      12  
    8      43  
    9      99  
    10    567
    11     55
    12      6
    13     55
    14     56
    15      1
    16    444
    17     66 
    18     89
    19      6    


table2
    id someval 
    -----------
    1     23.3 
    2     5.6  
    3     8.76 
    4     4.56 
    5      5.3 
    6      6.7 
    7      1.2 
    8      4.3 
    9      9.9 
    10    56.7
    11     6.7
    12    44.8
```

What query would join them and output (id is modified for second table):

### table1AND2

```
    id someval 
    -----------
    1      23  
    2      56  
    3      76  
    4     456  
    5      53  
    6      67  
    7      12  
    8      43  
    9      99  
    10    567
    11     55
    12      6
    13     55
    14     56
    15      1
    16    444
    17     66 
    18     89
    19      6   
    20    23.3 
    21    5.6  
    22    8.76 
    23    4.56 
    24    5.3 
    25    6.7 
    26    1.2 
    27    4.3 
    28    9.9 
    29    56.7
    30    6.7
    31    44.8
```

Is there a way to do this in general for any 2 tables of any row size?

Comment: Can you please explain the logic that makes the last row `12` and not `31`?

Comment: "Any two tables" meaning what exactly? Meaning some routine that could be passed "CelebrityDrunkenBingeVideos" and "NunAccessoryInventory" and it would magically produce a resultset of the two "supposedly" joined?

Comment: Well, we are supposing, any two tables (that have the structure `autoincrement id and value fields`)

Comment: From where are the last five rows derived?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT a.id,
         a.someval
    FROM TABLE1 a
UNION ALL
  SELECT b.id + (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE1) AS id,
         b.someval
    FROM TABLE2 b
ORDER BY id
```

`UNION` removes duplicates; `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates, and is faster for it.

To insert into another table:

```
INSERT INTO another_table
  SELECT a.id,
         a.someval
    FROM TABLE1 a
UNION ALL
  SELECT b.id + (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE1) AS id,
         b.someval
    FROM TABLE2 b
ORDER BY id
```

...that's assuming there's only two columns, id & somecol/etc, in the new table.

Comment: How would you insert this into another temporal table?

Comment: If you use the FROM clause rather than the SELECT clause to get the max value, the query will scale much more easily. ...UNION ALL SELECT b.id + **maxid.value**, b.someval FROM table2 AS b **CROSS APPLY (SELECT max(id) AS value FROM table1) AS maxid** ORDER BY id. When the subquery is in the SELECT clause, the subquery is executed once per row.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Was unable to test it at the moment...

```
SELECT identity(int,1,1) as id, 
   (
       SELECT someval FROM table1 
       UNION 
       SELECT someval FROM table2
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can produce the output you asked by using a `Union All` predicate and pulling the highest value from the first table.

```
Select id, somevalue From Table1
Union All
Select id
    + (Select Max(id) From Table1)
    , somevalue 
From Table2
```

Another solution would be to use a CTE:

```
With UnionedData As
    (
    Select id, somevalue, 1 As Sort From Table1
    Union All
    Select id, somevalue, 2 From Table2
    )
Select Row_Number() Over( Order By Sort, Id ) As Id
    , somevalue
From UnionedData
```